# \if statement inside an environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

Ideally, I want to write

```
\newif\ifhint
\hintfalse
\newenvironment{myhint}{\ifhint}{\fi}
```

But,but, then the `\fi` is not read! I just want to put this whole bunch in comment, any other solution is welcome, save for changing all these environments in my 34 subfiles --

Many thanks in advance, it is some days that I struggle with that!
Best, O.

Comment: Have you seen the `comment` package?  It does something similar to what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 5):

Put the `\ifhint` inside a command:

```
\newif\ifhint
\hintfalse
\newcommand\myhint[1]{\ifhint #1\fi}
```

If you prefer to use an environment then can define one using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` together with the `b`-argument specifier provided by [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyHint}{ +b }{\ifhint#1\fi}{}
```

The `b`-argument specifier indicates the body of the environment and the `+b` allows the body to contain paragraph breaks.

For completeness, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newif\ifhint\hintfalse
\newcommand\myhint[1]{\ifhint #1\fi}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyHint}{ +b }{\ifhint#1\fi}{}

\begin{document}

  \myhint{This hint is hidden}

  \begin{MyHint}
    This hint is hidden
  \end{MyHint}

  \hinttrue

  \myhint{This hint is not hidden}

  \begin{MyHint}
    This hint is not hidden
  \end{MyHint}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A great many thanks! I just add: the command `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` also exists and does what you believe:) Best, Olivier

Answer (score 5):

Besides Andrew's fine answer, it may be useful to know *why* you don't get the expected result.

When you do

```
\newenvironment{foo}{<begin code>}{<end code>}
```

and TeX expands `\begin{foo}`, it does several things, among which recording what environment it has begun (so to avoid bad nesting) and after this and other bookkeeping activity, it puts the `<begin code>` in the input stream, starting to expand or execute commands.

Similarly, when TeX expands `\end{foo}` it will do some other bookkeeping and then put `<end code>` in the input stream.

In your case, the `<begin code>` is just `\ifhint`. When this returns true because of a previous `\hinttrue`, the effect is that TeX records the presence of the conditional (which is internally `\iftrue`) so that, when it finds the matching `\fi` it will be satisfied (basically, an internal counter is stepped, although the inner working is a bit more complex). Macros and commands will be expanded or executed normally.

However, when `\ifhint` returns false, the same internal counter is stepped in order to look for the matching `\fi`. However tokens will be discarded with no interpretation whatsoever; only (primitive) conditionals will be taken note of, for the purpose of matching the corresponding `\else` and `\fi`.

In particular, the tokens `\end{myhint}` (in your case) will be discarded and *not* expanded, so the `\fi` will never be seen. The LaTeX run will go to the end of the file, unless some stray `\fi` comes along (which is impossible with well formed code).

Why does

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myhint}{+b}{\ifhint#1\fi}{}
```

work? Because the `b` argument type tells TeX to look for `\end{myhint}` storing everything that comes along in memory. When it finds `\end{myhint}`, it will stop storing and will deliver the whole content in place of `#1`. Thus

```latex
\begin{myhint}
Some text
\end{myhint}
```

will deliver

```
\ifhint Some text\fi
```

in the input stream. The matching `\fi` is no longer hidden even if `\ifhint` returns false.

Actually something more is done, for instance the endline after `\begin{myhint}` will not add a space in the output, nor will an endline before `\end{myhint}` cause a space in the output.